# Ionic Modal slides in black screen

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-maps, ionic-framework

I'm trying to use a modal triggered from the ion-header-bar to overlay on top of a google map.  When I click 'login' it slides in a black screen.  I've heard of including bootstrap can cause the problem, however I'm not using bootstrap.

My guess is it has something to do with the google map, however I am at a loss as to what.  It could also have something to do with ui-href. I'd be happy to hear suggestions.

I realize that the navigating directly to login or signup will crash the app because the map is not loaded, however I doubt this will be an issue because the app will always load into the googlemap first.

app.js :

```
angular.module('stuffmobile', ['ionic', 'ngCordova'])
.constant('ApiEndpoint', {
  url: 'http://localhost:3000/api'
})

.run(function($ionicPlatform, Map) {
  $ionicPlatform.ready(function() {
    // Hide the accessory bar by default (remove this to show the accessory bar above the keyboard
    // for form inputs)
    if(window.cordova && window.cordova.plugins.Keyboard) {
      cordova.plugins.Keyboard.hideKeyboardAccessoryBar(true);
    }
    if(window.StatusBar) {
      StatusBar.styleDefault();
    }

    Map.init();
  });
})
.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {

  $stateProvider
  .state('map', {
    url: '/',
    templateUrl: 'templates/map.html',
    controller: 'MapCtrl',
    controllerAs: 'mapctrl'
  })  
  .state('login', {
    url: '/login',
    templateUrl: 'templates/login.html',
    controller: 'LoginCtrl',
    controllerAs: 'loginCtrl'
  })
  .state('signup', {
    url: '/signup',
    templateUrl: 'templates/signup.html',
    controller: 'SignUpCtrl',
    controllerAs: 'signUpCtrl'
  });


  $urlRouterProvider.otherwise("/");

});
```

index.js

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no, width=device-width">
    <title></title>


    <!-- compiled css output -->
    <link href="css/ionic.app.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- ionic/angularjs js -->
    <script src="lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js"></script>

    <!-- cordova script (this will be a 404 during development) -->
    <script src='lib/ngCordova/dist/ng-cordova.js'></script>
    <script src="cordova.js"></script>

    <!-- your app's js -->
    <script src="js/app.js"></script>
    <!-- controllers -->
    <script src="js/controllers/map-controller.js"></script>
    <script src="js/controllers/login-controller.js"></script>
    <script src="js/controllers/signup-controller.js"></script>
    <!-- services -->
    <script src="js/services/markers-service.js"></script>
    <script src="js/services/map-service.js"></script>
    <script src="js/services/local-service.js"></script>
    <script src="js/services/user-service.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body ng-app="stuffmobile">
    <ion-pane>
      <ion-header-bar class="bar-energized">
        <h1 class="title">Stuffmapper</h1>
        <div class="buttons">
          <button class="button button-clear" ui-sref='login'>Login</button>
          <button class="button button-clear" ui-sref='signup'>Sign Up</button>
        </div>
      </ion-header-bar>
      <ion-nav-view></ion-nav-view>
    </ion-pane>
    <!-- Including google maps-->
    <script src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=true"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

login-controller

```
angular.module('stuffmobile')
.controller('LoginCtrl', function($scope, $ionicModal, $window, $timeout, UserService){
  var login = this;
  $ionicModal.fromTemplateUrl('templates/login.html', {
    scope: $scope,
    animation: 'slide-in-up'
  }).then(function(modal) {
    $scope.modal = modal;
  });
  $scope.openModal = function() {
    $scope.modal.show();
  };
  $scope.closeModal = function() {
    $scope.modal.hide();
  };
  //Cleanup the modal when we're done with it!
  $scope.$on('$destroy', function() {
    $scope.modal.remove();
  });
  // Execute action on hide modal
  $scope.$on('modal.hidden', function() {
    // Execute action
  });
  // Execute action on remove modal
  $scope.$on('modal.removed', function() {
    // Execute action
  });
});
```

login.html

```
<script id="templates/login.html" type="text/ng-template">
  <ion-modal-view>
    <ion-header-bar>
      <h1 class="title">Login</h1>
    </ion-header-bar>
    <ion-content>
      Hello!
    </ion-content>
  </ion-modal-view>
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Usually the problem is a "conflict" between css.

On my project the problem was the bootstrap's css. To solve i getted a css customized with [getbootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com) removing on the css configuration the modal part.

To be precisly the `.modal` class in bootstrap.css set `display: hidden;`

On your code i don't see any css inclusion. Only the ionic once. But there is a difference between the ionic js path and the css path.

The first is `css/`

```
<link href="css/ionic.app.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

And the second `lib/ionic/js/`:

```
<script src="lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js"></script>
```

Maybe you need to add `lib/ionic/` to the first path:

```
<link href="lib/ionic/css/ionic.app.css" rel="stylesheet">
```